# I can't add cookies on python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I'm trying to enter a page and then add cookies on it, but it returns an error and I don't know why. I did it exactly like is written on the selenium docs, and here is the code i used:

```
local_path = rf'{os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=local_path)
driver.get('https://example.com/')
driver.add_cookie({'session': 'session token'})
driver.close()
```

And it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'name'`. 
I already thought that it could be the code trying to add cookies before the page is totally loaded, but it isn't. I put a `time.sleep(30)` between `get` and `add_cookie` and it returned the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was just a wrong usage of `add_cookie()`. The right way to send cookies is like this:

```
driver.addcookie({

    'name': 'session',
    'value': 'token'

})
```

My error was using directly the cookie name + the value, and not with the dict template.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. I forgot that the structure a cookie must be in for selenium is different from the one in requests.

Comment: I get this error: `'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'addcookie'`

Comment: @henrry should be driver.add_cookie()